# Attempted to divide by zero in SSRS Chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2012

This is a Pie Chart report. I have searched but still cannot resolve this issue with the message:

```
    Warning 1 [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Visible expression for the chart contains an error: Attempted to divide by zero
```

The single field for summation in the pie chart was checked against zero `(ISNULL(val,0))` in Sql and therefore referenced in the `"Value field"` of the Pie Chart as `"SUM(Val)"`.

Comment: what is the expression that is causing the error?

Comment: What is the Visibility property of the chart set to?, it looks like that's the area causing the problem. rather than any data you are trying to display.

Answer (score 0):

`(ISNULL(val,0))` will set a null value to 0. I haven't seen the expression that's causing the error, but if you're using that value as the divisor, that may be causing the error.

Again, I don't know what your expression is, but you might be able to do something like this to avoid an error (if the divisor is 0, it won't try dividing by it):

`iif(divisor > 0, dividend / divisor, 0)`

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't provide an answer to the question?  I was telling dLight that he could use the last line of my answer ( iif(...) ) to make sure there was no dividing by 0, which was the issue described in the warning pasted in the question.